# Full Calendar not displaying ANY google calendar events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have researched all day before posting this question, and have have had no luck. Hence I am now asking for some help!

I can not get any of my Google Calendar events to show on my site using FullCalendar. Not only are my events not showing, I can not even get the U.S. Holidays calendar to display like they do in the demo on FullCalendar.

I am hoping I am missing something very small, and someone will be able to catch it quickly. The calendar itself shows up correctly, but no events show.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <title>tegIdeas - Course Schedule</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/shame.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/gcal.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
              },
            eventSources: {
              googleCalendarApiKey: 'myApiKey',
              googleCalendarId: 'myCalendarId',
              className: 'fc-event-email'
              },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: false,  
        });
    });
  </script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a dummy question- Are you using the correct apiKey and calendarId instead of `'myApiKey'` and `'myCalendarId'`?

Also, if `'myApiKey'` and `'myCalendarId'` are variables you set previously in your code, they should NOT be warpped by `'`.

```
eventSources: {
    googleCalendarApiKey: myApiKey,
    googleCalendarId: myCalendarId
}
```

Comment: I just replaced both with placeholders for the purpose of asking this question. They are not in fact variables, that is just how I am used to writing things!

Comment: sorry. I just needed to ask... :c)

Comment: Other thing: Are you running the webpage through localhost or the file system (like file://c:etc)... You might get JS restrictions if not running under htttp or https

Comment: I'm running through the file system, as well as hosted on bitballoon, and neither are working. No errors in the console, but my Calendars API is showing 0 requests in the google dev console. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write the calendar function as below:

- Just events in place of eventSources
- Note the unwanted comma at the end of the `editable: false`

---

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'API_Key',
    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'Calendar_Id'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: false  
});
```

This worked for me.